# Bundle npm module 'cheerio' in K6 test

Tags: npm, k6

I am trying to create some tests using K6 framework from LoadImpact, but I am struggelig with including external NPM module following the instructions on their documentation site.

On loadImpacts documentations site they include a detailed example on just what I am after, modules that enable me to parse xml from a soap service response. But, I am unable to get this working! Now, I am a total javascript newbie, but I have been coding for many years and would really like to solve this. 
The can be found here: https://docs.k6.io/docs/modules#section-npm-modules
can anyone get this working? I need to run this on servers isolated from the Internet, so I am totaly dependent on creating the packages and transfer the required files.

According to the documentation a package is created like this

```
-- bundle `cheerio` npm module
git clone git@github.com:cheeriojs/cheerio.git
npm install browserify index.js -s cheerio > cheerio.js
```

My first question: In the folder I am residing when running this command a 'cheerio.js' file is created along with a a 'cheerio' folder and a 'node_modules' folder. 
the cheerio.js in my "root" directory only contains the following:

```
+ cheerio@0.22.0
+ index.js@0.0.3
+ browserify@16.2.3
updated 3 packages and audited 2829 packages in 2.221s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Back to LoadImpacts example on how to reference this package in a k6 javascript:

```
import cheerio from "./vendor/cheerio.js";
export default function() 
{
  const res = http.get("https://loadimpact.com/");
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.body);
```

What file is this, and where in the structure generated by browserify can I find it? I have tried to change this to point to 'index.js' in the 'cheerio' folder or cheerio.js found in 'cheerio/lib'. I will then receive a complaint about the first line in cheerio.js which defines a "parse" variable it cannot find:
`var parse = require("./parse'),`
if I change this to 
`var parse = require("./parse.js')`
it goes on to complain about missing 'htmlparser2' which I can also find in this structure, but it seems like the entire dependency structure is not working.

Can anybody give me some guidance on how to create a browserify package with dependencies for cheerio and how/what I need to copy to my k6 project to make this work like on the loadImpact site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The k6 docs for this definitely need some clarification, which I'll later do. The `vendor` folder currently mentioned there isn't something special, the docs are just missing a step to copy the `cheerio.js` and `xml2js.js` files that were generated by browserify to a new `vendor` folder in your k6 project.

For now, I'll try to offer a simplified explanation on how to achieve the same thing in a simpler way:

1. Create a new empty folder and go to it in a terminal
2. Run `npm install browserify cheerio` there (ignore the npm warnings about missing `package.json` or description)
3. Run `./node_modules/.bin/browserify ./node_modules/cheerio/ -s cheerio > cheerio.js` in that folder
4. The resulting `cheerio.js` file in the folder root should be the file you import from the k6 script:

```
import http from "k6/http";
import cheerio from "./cheerio.js";

export default function () {
    const res = http.get("https://loadimpact.com/");

    const $ = cheerio.load(res.body);

    console.log($('head title').text())
}
```

That should be it for a single npm library.

And if you need to use multiple npm packages, it might be better to invest some time into bundling them in a single browserified `.js` file. For example, if you need both the `cheerio` and the `xml2js` libraries mentioned in the k6 docs, you can do something like this:

1. Create a new empty folder
2. Add something like the following `package.json` file in it:

   ```
   {
     "name": "k6-npm-libs-demo",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "description": "just a simple demo of how to use multiple npm libs in k6",
     "main": "npm-main.js",
     "dependencies": {},
     "devDependencies": {
       "browserify": "*",
       "cheerio": "*",
       "xml2js": "*"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "install": "./node_modules/.bin/browserify npm-main.js -s npmlibs  > vendored-libs.js"
     },
     "author": "",
     "license": "ISC"
   }
   ```

   Of course, if you need different libraries than `cheerio` and `xml2js`, you need to adjust the `devDependencies` options.
3. Add an `npm-main.js` file like this (again, adjusting for the libraries you want):

   ```
   exports.xml2js = require('xml2js');
   exports.cheerio = require('cheerio');
   ```
4. Open that folder in a terminal and run `npm install`. That should result in the creation of a `vendored-libs.js` file in the root of the folder, which you can use in k6 like this:

   ```
   import http from "k6/http";
   import { cheerio, xml2js } from "./vendored-libs.js";

   export default function () {
       const res = http.get("https://loadimpact.com/");

       const $ = cheerio.load(res.body);
       console.log($('head title').text())

       var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>' +
           '<items xmlns="http://foo.com">' +
           ' <item>Foo</item>' +
           ' <item color="green">Bar</item>' +
           '</items>'

       xml2js.parseString(xmlString, function (err, result) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Alternatively for Node modules you can do `npx browserify -r cheerio -s cheerio > cheerio.js`. This will use the Node module loader to obtain the module's entry point instead of needing to guess the file path.